# How to add checkbox to the scrollviewer by code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

```
<Grid>
                <ScrollViewer Height="391" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="427" >
                    <Grid Height="733">

                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <TextBox Height="76" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,453,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254" />
                <Button Content="Button" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="290,450,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" />
            </Grid>
```

I want to add a checkbox in the scrollviewer when the user clicks the button. A new checkbox should appear below the previous at every click as well. And also, is the ScrollViewer the ideal control for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want checkboxes to appear below each other you should use a StackPanel instead of Grid as the container inside the SrollViewer:

```
   <ScrollViewer Height="391" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="427" > 
                <StackPanel Name="CheckBoxContainer">

                </StackPanel> 
   </ScrollViewer>
```

And in your click event you add the checkboxes

```
 CheckBoxContainer.Children.Add(new CheckBox());
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add the Checkbox to the grid that is contained within the ScrollViewer. This can be done using code similar to:

```
myGrid.Children.Add(new CheckBox());
```

assuming "myGrid" is the name of your grid.

The ScrollViewer is a good control to use when you have a limited area that needs to contain content that would not fit in that area normally. As I do not know what your application does, what it looks like, or how it works, it is pretty hard to say from a design point of view if it is the right control for this.

However, seeing as the user could potentially add 10's (even 100's) of Checkboxes, then you'd likely want this to not expand the form more than you would like it to.

Answer (score 1):

For the continues adding of check boxes use StackPanel instead Grid

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Height="391" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="427" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TextBox Height="76" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Margin="19,453,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="290,450,0,0" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" />
</Grid>
```

And than:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new CheckBox() { Content = "Hi"});
}
```